# Cannot Delete File using C# Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net

I am opening a file from a location (say, X) in a PictureBox.

After that, if the user clicks on a button say "btn1" then I copy the file from Location X to Location Y using `File.Copy()`.

After that I set the `Picturebox1.Image=null;` ...and use `File.Delete(X);`

At this point Visual studio shows me the exception that *The file cannot be deleted as it is being used by another process*.

Any ideas as to why would that be?

Answer (score 2):

Call `Picturebox1.Image.Dispose()`.

Comment: If this answer helped, then please click the "accepted answer" tickbox next to the question. This helps future visitors to this question know the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use File.Move() as workaround
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx

Comment: Thank you..I was not aware of this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are disposing the original `Image`.

Otherwise, another program has a handle on it.

Comment: I did try Picturebox1.Dispose()...but that didn't help either